# How to set the container width calculating the width of if its children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a container with n number of div inside it. I need the container to resize according to it children. I know this can be done using jquery library as follows.

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setContainerWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   setContainerWidth();
});

function setContainerWidth()
{
    $('.container').css('width', 'auto'); //reset
    var windowWidth = $(document).width();
    var blockWidth = $('.block').outerWidth(true);
    var maxBoxPerRow = Math.floor(windowWidth / blockWidth);
    $('.container').width(maxBoxPerRow * blockWidth);
}
```

This time I need to do this with the pure javascript for some plugin issue. I broke down the code till as follows and stuck in the middle any help would be appreciated.

**Javascript**

```
function setContainerWidth(){
    var container_width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
    var width = document.body.clientWidth
    var block_width = document.getElementsByClassName("block").offsetWidth;

    container.style.width = "auto"
    var maxBoxPerRow = Math.floor(width / block_width)
    container.offsetWidth(maxBoxPerRow * block_width)
}
```

[Example one using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/jx8jman0/2/)

[Example two using javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/jx8jman0/3/)

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements. You'll want to use `document.getElementsByClassName('block')[0]`

Comment: i tried it previous and it didnt work in ma case

Comment: Even tried `id` instead `class` for box still no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a few things from your pure javascript translation:

```
function setContainerWidth()
{
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.style.width = "auto";
    var window_width = window.innerWidth;
    var block_width = document.getElementsByClassName("block")[0].offsetWidth;
    var maxBoxPerRow = Math.floor(window_width / block_width);
    container.style.width = (maxBoxPerRow * block_width) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: how do I use this on window resize using pure js

Comment: Like this `window.onresize = function(event) { ... };`